# clang-format Allman style won't work

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I made my `.clang-format` and tried formatting my c file using it but the output is different from what I set it to be. In my `.clang-format` I manually set each thing in `BraceWrapping` to `true` and it doesn't work, but even in the

```
BasedOnStyle: None
AlignTrailingComments: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 4
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Did I do something wrong or is there a bug in my clang-format version? I'm using version `4.0.0`

Comment: Everything in BraceWrapping is ignored if BreakBeforeBraces isn't set to Custom.  When you say you manually set each thing to true, did you also have BreakBeforeBraces set to Custom?

Comment: @DavidVereb Yes, I did.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some example code so that we can try to reproduce the error on our end?  Are you sure it's seeing your .clang-format file?